# Cannot modify Python string/list variables (used by tkinter) from other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm re-engineering ("object"-ifying) a Python 3.2 GUI application that automatically adapts tkinter GUI objects (button labels) to the language of the user (determined at startup and never changes).  As the first step I am breaking the large, single source file into multiple module files.  I was able to move some functions into their own module files without problems - but other "proven good" functions will not work when invoked from their own module file.

"IndexError: string index out of range" errors are occurring when trying to use a variable ("Database_to_use", see below) that resides in one module and is set up by a different (sibling) module.  The error does NOT occur when the procedure that modifies the variable is in the mainline module.  I suspected a scoping problem and/or name clash but from everything I've read and done seems to have eliminated both possibilities.

I am using "import ", dotted references, and am placing global declarations in the modifying functions.  Dotted notation is also being used to "rename" entities in a way that that abstracts the name away from the implementation detail of where it resides - and also limits the scope of a module name change to one line inside a module.  I checked that this approach isn't causing name hiding issues; the same problem occurred after I renamed the problem module AND the problem function (the "SelectSqlDatabase" module, below).  BTW I'm also well aware of the advantages and drawbacks of globals (which will eventually disappear).

In the following extracts I've severely edited the code (e.g. only shown code for one button) to remove everything that is not essential to understanding the problem.

First the "SetUpLanguageInUse.py" module; this is the location of the problematic "Database_to_use" (and the problem-free "Main_Title") variable:

```
English  = 'English'
Francais = 'Francais'

Database_to_use = "dummy string forces this variable into the global namespace"
Main_Title      = "dummy string forces this variable into the global namespace"

def SetUpLanguageInUse( user_language ):

    import __main__     # needed to modify the global value 

    if ( user_language == English ):       
        __main__.Main_Title      = 'Monthly Summary of Reports'
        __main__.Database_to_use = ( '', 'Build', 'Staging', 'Production' )
    elif ( user_language == Francais ):
        __main__.Main_Title       = 'Resume Mensuel de Rapports' 
        __main__.Database_to_use  = ( '', 'Construire', 'Relais', 'Production' )

    .....

    return
```

Some observations about the above module:

a) The problem is independent of the user language.
b) Using [] instead of () didn't fix the problem.
c) Inserting "global Database_to_use" lines inside (and/or before) the function did not help
d) removing the dummy string assignments did not help
e) The very first line of the mainline (see below) calls this function.  When the function contained "global " lines the variables were not updated.  I understand why using "**main**." works - but why doesn't modification work when "global" lines are present?

Next, the "SelectSqlDatabase.py" module, it holds the problem function:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import LanguageInUse

Database_to_use = LanguageInUse.Database_to_use

Database_List  = ( '', 'server1', 'server2', 'server3' )
SQL_Database   = "To be determined"

# ----- the problematic function

def SelectSqlDatabase( SelectDatabaseFrame ) : 

    global SQL_Database

    UserSelection = StringVar( value = "Empty" )

    Build_DB      = Radiobutton( SelectDatabaseFrame, 
                                 text        = Database_to_use[ 1 ],  # the problematic line
                                 variable    = UserSelection, 
                                 value       = Database_List[ 1 ] )

    SQL_Database = UserSelection.get()

    return
```

Finally the mainline.  Notice that inthis file the "SelectSqlDatabase" function is a COMMENT and is IDENTICAL to that in 
"SelectSqlDatabase.py".  When this code is run "AS IS" (i.e. using the function in "SelectSqlDatabase.py"), I get the following error:

File "...\SelectSqlDatabase.py", line 65, in SelectSqlDatabase
    text        = Database_to_use[ 1 ],
IndexError: string index out of range

But when I UN-comment the function (thereby hiding the function in "SelectSqlDatabase.py"), the application runs correctly!

```
from tkinter  import *
from tkinter  import ttk

import LanguageInUse
import SelectSqlDatabase       

Database_to_use          = LanguageInUse.Database_to_use
Database_List            = SelectSqlDatabase.Database_List
English                  = LanguageInUse.English
SetUpLanguageInUse       = LanguageInUse.SetUpLanguageInUse
SQL_Database             = SelectSqlDatabase.SQL_Database

SelectSqlDatabase        = SelectSqlDatabase.SelectSqlDatabase     # gets overridden

# ----- the problematic function

'''
def SelectSqlDatabase( SelectDatabaseFrame ) : 

    global SQL_Database

    UserSelection = StringVar( value = "Empty" )

    Build_DB      = Radiobutton( SelectDatabaseFrame, 
                                 text        = Database_to_use[ 1 ],  # the problematic line
                                 variable    = UserSelection, 
                                 value       = Database_List[ 1 ] )

    SQL_Database = UserSelection

    return
'''
'''----------'''
def ChooseDataSourceFrame( mainframe ) :

    ChooseSourceFrame   = ttk.LabelFrame( mainframe, ...  )
    SelectDatabaseFrame = ttk.LabelFrame( ChooseSourceFrame )

    SelectSqlDatabase( SelectDatabaseFrame )

    return

'''***** MAINLINE ***** '''

SetUpLanguageInUse( English )      #TODO: make language a startup parameter

mainframe = ttk.Frame( ... )

ChooseDataSourceFrame( mainframe )
```

To be complete, at one time I was able to eliminate this error (by passing "Database_to_use" as a parameter) but other nasty things happened such as:
a) the GUI displaying the useless dummy titles (effectively ignoring the call to "SetUpLanguageInUse"), 
b) getting an error message about "Database_to_use" not having a get() function, or
c) the value returned in "SQL_Database" being either it's default value ("To be determined") or the default value for User_Choice ("Empty") instead of the database chosen by the user.

To summarize, my objective is to set "SQL_Database" to the database server chosen by the user (i.e. extracted from
"Database_List") - with tkinter displaying the (language-dependent) strings passed to it inside "Database_to_use".

I've spent a LOT of time experimenting & researching this problem - all to no avail.  Everything I've read (including the Python 3.2.3 Tutorial) suggests that what I'm doing is correct, however I feel I'm overlooking something simple.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First comment: "but why doesn't modification work when "global" lines are present?"

 They do work. I even tested with your code above to make sure, and they did.

Comment: Second comment: "IndexError: string index out of range"

 Then your code is not what you showed.`Database_to_use` is set to `"dummy string forces this variable into the global namespace"`, hence `Database_to_use[1]` should be `"u"`. Since you get an index error, it's set to a string that is one or zero characters long, which is not what you have in the code you are showing. Please make sure you actually reduce the code to a minimum to show the error, and then post exactly that code.

Comment: I omitted two factors in my "global" question.  The question arose before there were references to "*__main__*" in the module AND the code attempting to use the variables is external to that module.  In light of Lennart's solution (below) I'm now thinking that the mystery was caused by another case of not using the correct object.

Comment: Concerning the second comment, the code is "as stated" - but that's no longer important.  What Lennart says about Database_To_Use[1]  being "u" certainly makes sense - and it explains how/why I got misled by the error message.  The intent of "SetUpLanguageInUse" is to set the value of "Database_To_Use" to the language-specific TUPLE (or list) defined inside that function. *In that mindset I misinterpreted the error message as referring to TUPLE element 1, not to position 1 of the dummy) string.*  In other words I fell afoul of another occurrence of the same general problem.

Comment: The only reason I used the *kluge* of using dummy strings was that placing a "global Database_To_Use" line (as a sort of deferred  declaration) in the module's global namespace didn't work.  **Is there a better way to force the name (with everything else about being resolved at run time) into the modules global namespace?**

Comment: The program is built and run on WinXP under Eclipse (Helios) as a pydev console application.  It also builds and runs under Eclipse (juno) on 32 bit Win7.

Comment: Also see my comments attached to the answer from @Lennart

Comment: BTW, using *__main__* (found in another stackoveflow question) was a desperation play - and a bad idea  It seems to have caused the global to become immutable!  Going back to my first approach (the basic one suggested by Lennart) avoided this effect.

Comment: From the Zen of Python (import this): "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing here is that Python does *not* have variables that are pointers, they are references to objects. Hence, when you change a variable name, that variable name will point to the new object you created. All other variable names will continue to point to the old variable.

Hence, when you import `Database_to_use` into SelectSqlDatabase it will point to the string object `"dummy string forces this variable into the global namespace"`. When your function later changes the `Database_to_use` name in your first file to point to another string, this will not modify what `SelectSqlDatabase.Database_to_use` references. It will continue to reference the original string.

So, what should you do? You should keep your run-time configurations in an object of some sort, and always look up the variables from that object, so that you do not keep your configuration variables in local variables that do not change.

So in this case, to solve the problem, remove the line

```
Database_to_use = LanguageInUse.Database_to_use
```

And just reference `LanguageInUse.Database_to_use` all the time instead, it would probably solve the problem.

It's still a bit ugly though. I would probably just have a `configuraion = {}` in your main `__init__.py`, and use that:

Setting:

```
from mainmodule import configuration

def somefuction():
    configuration['database'] = "mysql:blahblahblah"
```

Using:

```
from mainmodule import configuration
configuration['database'] = "mysql:blahblahblah"

def somefuction():
    databaseopener(cofiguration['database'])
```

Also: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: My thanks to @Lennart.  His statement "*...when you change a variable name, that variable name will point to the new object you created...*" was the wake-up call that pointed out the general problem. **The suggestion to remove the "renaming" line and use dotted notation eliminated the index error** and got tkinter to display the correct string.

Comment: I got tripped up by my ADA (etc.) background.  In that language a line like "*A renames ModuleB.A*" will set up a very useful alias that allows "A" to be used *everywhere* Python requires you to use "ModuleB.A" .  This approach "worked" in Python - until I had to *write* a value into "ModuleB.A".  (BTW, **Is there a way to do this type of aliasing in Python?**)

Comment: I also see that I attempted to do too much at the same time.  As per the FAQ (and the suggestion about *__init__.py*) my first step should be to put all cross-module variables into a "config" module that is imported by all modules.  Then, after all functions have been placed into their new modules, move the variables from the "config" file into the appropriate module, updating the config file accordingly.  Voila - after that is done I should be able to convert each module into a proper object that uses gets(), sets() etc., thus eventually eliminating the need for the config file.

Comment: As to PEP8, the program started as a throwaway to learn tkinter & python - but management very quickly saw it as being something essential.  It's also become my first significant python application, hence the need for reorganization and associated wart removal.

Comment: Also see my comments attached to my original post.

Comment: BTW, there reason I ask about aliasing is that this trick allows you to use external objects in an abstract manner - i.e. without the visual "noise" of having to prepend the object with it's module name.  It also limits the impact of moving something from one module to one line - the alias line.

Comment: @user1459519: No, I don't think there is no way to do that kind of aliasing in Python. Even the idea that the module name is visual noise rather goes against Python's principles. In Python, we *like* namespaces. writing `module.configname` is seen as explicit and clear, not noise. :-)